# How to plot histogram with means calculated by factor levels from multiple columns

Tags: r, histogram

I am new to R and may be my question looks silly, I spent half of the day trying to solve it on my own with no luck. I've found no tutorial which illustrates how to do it, and if you know such tutorial you're welcome. I want to plot a histogram with means calculated by factors from columns. My initial data looks like this (simplified version):

```
code_group scale1  scale2
   1           5       3
   2           3       2
   3           5       2
```

So I need histogram where each bean colored by code_group and it's value is mean for each level from code_group, x-axis with labels scale1 and scale2. Every label contains three beans (for three levels of factor code_group). I've managed to calculate means for each level on my own, it looks like this:

```
code_group    scale1      scale2 
    1       -1.0270270   0.05405405   
    2       -1.0882353   0.14705882
    3       -0.7931034   -0.34482759
```

but I have no idea how to plot it in historgam! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you really want a histogram, or rather a bar plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean *bar chart* and not *histogram* (please clarify your question if this isn't the case), you can `melt` your data and plot it with `ggplot` like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
##
mdf <- melt(
  df,
  id.vars="code_group",
  variable.name="scale_type",
  value.name="mean_value")
##
R> ggplot(
    mdf,
    aes(x=scale_type,
        y=mean_value,
        fill=factor(code_group)))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")
```

[image]

---

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(
  text="code_group    scale1      scale2 
    1       -1.0270270   0.05405405   
    2       -1.0882353   0.14705882
    3       -0.7931034   -0.34482759",
  header=TRUE)
```

---

**Edit:**
You could just make the modifications to the data itself (or a copy of it) like below:

```
mdf2 <- mdf
mdf2$code_group <- factor(
  mdf2$code_group,
  levels=1:3,
  labels=c("neutral",
           "likers",
           "lovers"))
names(mdf2)[1] <- "group"
##
ggplot(
  mdf2,
  aes(x=scale_type,
      y=mean_value,
      fill=group))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")
##
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution works fine, but I've found that I can't change apperance of the legend and labels, for example:   image = ggplot(
      mdf,
      aes(x=scale_type,
      y=mean_value,
      fill=factor(code_group)))+
      geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge");
  image + xlab("Age in years") + ylab("Height in inches");
  image + scale_shape_discrete(name="groups", na.value = "grey50", breaks=c(1,2,3), labels=c("neutral", "likers", "lovers"));
that's all not working

Answer (score 0):

Given the mean values you provided, you could do something like this:

To recreate your simplified dataset:

```
d=data.frame(code_group=c(1,2,3),scale1=c(-1.02,-1.08,-0.79),scale2=c(0.05,.15,-0.34))
```

To create your graph:

```
barplot(c(d[,'scale1'],d[,'scale2']),col=d[,'code_group'],names.arg=c(paste('scale1',unique(d[,'code_group']),sep='_'),paste('scale2',unique(d[,'code_group']),sep='_')))
```

This will give you the following graph:

[image]